# Freeing vectors of vectors after use

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, free

I would like to free the following vectors after each use:

```
    std::vector<std::array<double,640>> A(480);
    std::vector<std::array<double,640>> B(480);
    std::vector<std::array<double,640>> C(480);
    std::vector<std::array<double,640>> D(480);
```

Some of all vectors I'am having are accumulating each second of loop few megabytes from the Commit and I really don't want that because I want to use my app in some non high powerful machines.

Then, how to free those vectors?

Comment: You don't. That's the nice thing about them.

Comment: A.clear() will clear vector A

Comment: @someone_smiley: There is no guarantee the implementation will actually free the vector's memory.

Comment: @syam : not sure about "guarantee the implementation will actually free the vector's memory", can you please give some reference to your claim?

Comment: @someone_smiley I've got no time to look into the standard right now, I hope [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) is enough to convince you: "*Many implementations will not release allocated memory after a call to `clear()`, effectively leaving the `capacity()` of the vector unchanged.*"

Comment: @someone_smiley In fact, there is a guarantee that `clear` won't free any memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "accumulating".  Could you give some example of the code you're using which is causing the problem?  Normally, if the vectors are defined within a loop, all of the memory should be freed at the end of the loop (each time through).  If they are declared outside the loop, they will only exist as a single instance; there will be no accumulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a vector goes out of scope, the memory it has occupied is released automatically (including calling the destructors of the contained objects). So if you have high memory requirements, you should make sure to use the vectors in the smallest possible scope.

to give an example

```
void reallyGreedyFunc()
{
    // next allocates the memory for 480 fixed size arrays of 640 doubles on the heap
    // only the management structures will be kept on the stack
    std::vector<std::array<double,640>> A(480);

    //... do something
} // A goes out of scope and all the memory it has occupied is released
```

Answer (score 3):

To free the contents of a `vector`, just let it go out of scope or be destroyed along with the class instance it belongs to (depending on your exact situation).

If you can't wait that long, you can always use the good old `swap-with-empty` idiom to ensure the memory is actually freed:

```
std::vector<std::array<double,640>>().swap(A);
// or, nicer version using C++11's decltype, which avoids typing the exact type:
decltype(A)().swap(A);
```

Comment: if it goes out of scope, the memory is freed anyway. The swapping approach is mostly useful to trim a vector to its smallest possible size if may elements have been removed from it, while still keeping the vector itself.

Comment: @ogni42 Depending on the exact code, it may be necessary/useful to get rid of its contents before it goes out of scope. There's also the same issue if the vector is a member of a long-lived class. Whatever the case, OP wants to completely free the memory used by vector before its lifetime ends so the swap idiom is useful.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Clearing the mem in a long lived class is a nice use case for that.